# Why is the setter not visited when using .Add?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to set a flag when a collection is modified - the logical place to do that seemed to be in the setter method.  The problem is when I use this code

```
setterDemo1.Widgets.Add(new Widget)
```

m_widgetSetterVisited is not set to True.
Does anyone see what I'm missing here?
Thanks,
Dave

```
Public Class SetterDemo

    Private m_Widgets As List(Of Widget) = New List(Of Widget)
    Public m_widgetSetterVisited As Boolean = False

    Public Property Widgets() As List(Of Widget)
        Get
            Return m_Widgets
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Widget))
            m_widgetSetterVisited = True
            m_Widgets = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Widget

    Public Name As String
    Public Age As Integer

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example code, you are performing a `get` on the field, and then calling a method on the returned object of type `List`.  Notice that you are never setting the value of the field `m_Widgets`.  In short, this won't work.

I think to accomplish what you want to do, you would need to either inherit from a class in the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace (or `List` if that is not possible) and override the various methods that add and remove members, or encapsulate `List` and implement `IList` yourself, dispatching to the internal list as necessary.  Alternatively, you may be able to use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which fires an event when objects are added/removed.

EDIT - Incorperating Gideon's note to use `System.ObjectModel.Collection` if possible

Comment: Many thanks I will look at all these excellent answers.  I would have thought that the setter would be called because by adding a new member I am changing the value of .Widgets and therefore am writing to it.

Comment: `List` is not the preferred base class (though there may be external issues that could require that approach).  When making collections, you should derive from `System.ObjectModel.Collection`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only alters your `m_widgetSetterVisited` flag when setting the `List(Of Widget)` itself - not when accessing its members. So you would need code like this to trigger it:

```
setterDemo.Widgets = New List(Of Widget)
```

or

```
setterDemo.Widgets = OtherWidgetObject
```

Simply manipulating the members of that reference will not work.

Comment: I would be interested in responding to the thoughts of anyone who marked this answer as not helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that we handle this is to have all of our collections inherit from [System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) or [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).

These collections have methods that are designed to be overridden (InsertItem, RemoveItem, ClearItems, and SetItem) that will be fired whenever a change is made to the items in the collection.

You can override each of these methods and set your flag as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ObservableCollection` which supports the `IList<T>` interface and also supports collection changed notification:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Public Class ChangedDemo

    Private m_Widgets As ObservableCollection(Of Widget) = New ObservableCollection(Of Widget)
    Public m_WidgetsChanged As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler m_Widgets.CollectionChanged, AddressOf m_Widgets_CollectionChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_Widgets_CollectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        m_WidgetsChanged = True
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Widgets() As IList(Of Widget)
        Get
            Return m_Widgets
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```